# Microsoft Graph Permissions overlaps

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-app-registration, microsoft-entra-id

I'm trying to understand Microsoft Graph Permissions (The ones you add to an App Registration) and have encountered some overlaps and hierarchical relationships among them. However, I'm struggling to find a comprehensive description or hierarchy tree that outlines which permissions are covered by others and the overall structure.

Could anyone point me in the right direction or provide insights into where I can find detailed information regarding these permission overlaps?

Any documentation or references you could share would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: There are multiple Microsoft Graph API permissions which overlaps or have hierarchy.

For **sample**: The Microsoft Graph API permissions `User.ReadWrite.All` overlaps `User.Read.All`.

- **`User.ReadWrite.All`** allows the application to read and write all user profile properties.
- **`User.Read.All`** allows the application to read all user profile properties.

`User.ReadWrite.All` includes all the permissions of `User.Read.All` and hence if you want to allow the application to read and write all user profile properties, then you can only assign `User.ReadWrite.All` not `User.Read.All`.

I created a **Microsoft Entra ID application** and granted `User.ReadWrite.All` API permission:

[image]

Generated **access token** via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

[image]

Decoded token:

[image]

Hence by using the above token **the application can read and write the user profile**:

*Read User profile:*

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID
```

[image]

*Write User profile:*

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID

{
"businessPhones": [
"xxx"
],
"officeLocation": "18/2111"
}
```

[image]

- Same with `Application.Read.All` and `Application.ReadWrite.All`, `Files.Read.All` and `Files.ReadWrite.All` and many more.
- You can understand the overlap or hierarchy of the Microsoft Graph API permissions by the permission description.

For more detail, **refer** the below MsDoc:

[Microsoft Graph permissions reference - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#permission-hierarchy)